# How Update Google Drive file in Colab without version history?

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api, parquet, google-colaboratory

everyone. I use colab and big dataset for my task.. about 10Gb dataset divided into 50 parts (I use parquet)... and it's 1GB of free space left. When I try to update my dataset_parts.parquet files on goole drive, GD create new verion of my file. I don't need it, because I don't have free space for it.
So, How I can update my files without verion control?

```
#its example of my code
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import pands as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('/content/drive/MyDrive/file_0.parquet',columns=columns)
df['amnt']=df['coral']/10
df.to_parquet('/content/drive/MyDrive/file_0.parquet, compression='gzip')
```

Comment: `!rm /content/drive/MyDrive/file_0.parquet` as workaround before uploading again

Comment: It doesn't work))

Comment: For me it does? Im not sure why it wont for you